# Is it possible to do an Online Index Rebuild in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to do an Online Index Rebuild in Postgresql or is your only option to do a drop and recreate?  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-reindex.html

Comment: `REINDEX { INDEX | TABLE | DATABASE | SYSTEM } name [ FORCE ]`, locks out writes but not reads of the parent table while it does it's thing. See: [REINDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-reindex.html)

Comment: @Brian Thank you for your reply.  So only the table is accessible but the old index is not right.  So operations will be done without the index performance enhancement?

Comment: Note that REINDEX will not perform a concurrent build. To build the index without interfering with production you should drop the index and reissue the CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY command.

Answer (score 3):

To rebuild `my_idx`,

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY new_my_idx ON my_table (my_column);
BEGIN;
DROP INDEX my_idx;
ALTER new_my_idx RENAME TO my_idx;
COMMIT;
```

With the usual caveats on `CONCURRENTLY` (it will take longer, as it must wait for any pending writes to finish, twice).